# JAVA- NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The following code shows the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at cdtWorkspace.swap.main(swap.java:25)

PS: I have initialized a scanner object globally as `static`.

```
15 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
16    
17            int n=scn.nextInt();
18            int[][] param=new int[n][2];
19            int[][] arr=new int[n][];
20            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
21                param[i][0]=scn.nextInt();
22                param[i][1]=scn.nextInt();
23                int j=0;
24                while (j<param[i][0]){
25                    arr[i][j]=scn.nextInt();
26                    j++;
27                }
28            }
29 }
```

I am getting the same error each time i try to fill in an array using a for loop! 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you initialise `scn`? No? There's your problem.

Comment: @Quirliom No, that's not the problem. The error is on line 25, not line 17.

Comment: You have to initialize scanner object as, Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @Quirliom and Sanjaya Pandey , yes i do intialize the Scanner object.
the error is in line 25..

Comment: First of all, show your entire (reproducible) error-prone code, and second of all, stop typing in all caps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 23 - 27 to

```
arr[i] = new int[param[i][0]];
for( int j = 0; j < param[i][0]; j++ ){  // prefer for to while
    arr[i][j] = scn.nextInt();
}
```

It should be obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
           int[][] arr=new int[n][];
```

Makes it so arr is an array of n arrays. However those arrays are empty

When you do this

```
 arr[i][j]=scn.nextInt();
```

You're accessing columns(because the array at that row has size 0) that don't exist, hence null pointer exception
`

Comment: Watch your language! An "empty array" is what you get when you say `new int[0]`, but after that `new int[n][]` there aren't any arrays *within* `arr` at all; `arr` contains `n` times `null`.

Comment: when you do matrix[1].length, i saw it was 0 so I assumed it was just an empty array

Comment: Well, `int[][] a = new int[3][]; System.out.println( a[1].length );` does throw a NPE. Please fix your answer. `int[][] a = new int[3][0];` gives you "empty" arrays.